# Get notification when a file has not been updated on cPanel

Tags: notifications, cron, cpanel, jobs

We are using cPanel for our website. I know how we can get notifications when a file has been updated or changed, but we want to get notifications only if a file has not been updated at 06:00 AM.

In cPanel we have Cron Job but it only sends notifications if it has been changed. Our file updates everyday at 06:00 AM and we want to only get notifications if it has not has been changed.

This command `find /home/USER/public_html -type f -ctime -1 -exec ls -ls {} \;` is doing the job, but it sends an email everyday, it will be fine with a similar command, but I only want to get a notification if it has not been changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create bash script using If..then..fi statement for this task.